# htaccess remove end slash if question mark in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, slash

I'm not able to figure out this problem in .htaccess
I need to remove last slash from each URL, which has question mark.

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/?search=abcd/
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/?search=abcd
```

But only, if there is question mark in URL

Comment: What do you have so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that could work (untested) :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)/$
RewriteRule (.*) %2?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Your solution removes last slash, but change URL:

http://domain.com/directory/?search=abc/

to

http://domain.com/data/web/domain.com/web/?search=abc

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(search=[^&]+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [L,R]
```

Comment: It's doing the same like KRTEK solution:
It removes last slash, but change URL: domain.com/directory/?search=abc to domain.com/data/web/domain.com/web/?search=abc

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found solution that works...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1 [R=301,L]
```